# MySQL - INNER JOIN - take only the last ID from the second table

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I need to query two tables in my MySQL database.
Here is the short overview: 2 tables: articles and article_logs. I have somethink like 2700 articles and each article can have from 20 to 50 logs.
I would like to display for each article the last log date. 
The problem is that the query takes forever to be executed.

I am trying somethin like that:

```
SELECT articles.id, article_logs.date FROM articles
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT MAX(id), hash_key, date FROM logs GROUP BY id ) c 
ON article.hash_key = c.hash_key
```

Do you have an idea on how to do this in a proper and efficient way.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: tip: `date` is MySQL reserve keyword so wrap it with `\``

Comment: Using `max(id)` and `group by id` together doesn't make sense. And any other DBMS would simply reject this incorrect `group by` usage.

Comment: @diEcho, date was only as an example, in my table, the name of the field is log_date... Thank you for this.

Comment: additional with above comment : http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, So should I delete the group by ?

Comment: Read this: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html to understand how `group by` and aggregates work.

Comment: @diEcho `date` can be used withput backtick, [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) see the last part of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, 
       (SELECT MAX(l.date)
        FROM logs l
        WHERE l.hash_key = a.hash_key) date
FROM articles a
```

Comment: Milos my query works only if you need max date for `hash_key`. But if you need date for MAX `id` (like in your query), query must be changed. Now I'm guessing that max `date` always have max `id`. If something don't gonna work write a comment and I edit answer.

Comment: yes, I need the max date for the specific hash_key, because each article is identified by a unique hash_key.